# View XAML Code in a Box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I want to make something like a XAML Viewer where I Input a XAML Code Graphic over a String and Output in a Viewer.

The Rectangle code should not be directly in the scroll viewer, rather issue over a string...but I dont now how I can do it...

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="viewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

                <Rectangle Name="Rectangle" Height="20" Width="30" Fill="GreenYellow" />

        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Use the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and use [KAXAML](http://www.kaxaml.com/), it does exactly what you need... If you still want to make your own XAML viewer/editor, download [KAXAML source code](http://kaxaml.codeplex.com/), it will have all the code you need to get started...

Comment: I dont really understand the KAXAML Source Code... Yes, I want to make my own viewer/editor...